# Is it possible to get iterator value without switch to the next position:

Tags: rust, iterator

In C++ I can get current value of iterator many times

```
int main() {
    std::string s = "abcd";
    auto iter = s.begin();
    std::cout << *iter << std::endl; // a
    std::cout << *iter << std::endl; // a
}
```

Can I do the same in Rust?
Is it possible to get iterator value without switch to the next position:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("abcd");
    let mut iter = s.chars();
    println!("{:?}", iter.next()); // get Some(a) and switch to the next position    
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for a [peekable iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html). You can make your iterator peekable with `let mut iter = s.chars().peekable()` and then peek the next value without consuming it with `iter.peek()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("abcd");
    let mut iter = s.chars().peekable();
    println!("{:?}", iter.peek()); // get Some(a)    
    println!("{:?}", iter.peek()); // get Some(a)    
}
```